# IE 11: Error while sending Multipart Form Data request: Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-11, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload files along with some other form fields using jQuery AJAX calls.

This is a common function that calls the URL on the server:

```
function uploadDocument(rquestURL,formId,callback){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : rquestURL,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            data : new FormData($("#"+formId)[0])
        }).done(function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
}
```

On examining from the dev tools from browsers, these are the respective request contents:

**From IE11**

```
-----------------------------7dfad39402e6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Test
-----------------------------7dfad39402e6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

Test test
-----------------------------7dfad39402e6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="announcementAttachment"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<Binary File Data Not Shown>
---------------------------7dfad39402e6
```

**Chrome**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryp8rj3ArKDsbYw0BZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Test
------WebKitFormBoundaryp8rj3ArKDsbYw0BZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

Test test
------WebKitFormBoundaryp8rj3ArKDsbYw0BZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="announcementAttachment"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryp8rj3ArKDsbYw0BZ--
```

On server side, we are parsing the request as:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        // get the request content and iterate through
        items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
}
```

The code works fine from Chrome and Firefox, but throws the below exception when I tried from IE11.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly
```

I referred to these SO questions but in vain.

- [Java - FormData in IE throwing org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788517/java-formdata-in-ie-throwing-org-apache-commons-fileupload-multipartstreammal)
- [Grails Multipart Service Stream ended unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714527/grails-multipart-service-stream-ended-unexpectedly)

Any useful pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just going to put it out here, because it is not exactly an answer to this specific problem, but if there are those few of you out there desperately looking for an answer to "Stream ended unexpectedly" issues using Spring or Spring Boot, it might be due to your version of Spring using Tomcat v9.0.31 which causes larger requests to be cut off out of nowhere. [This article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-we-found-apache-tomcat-couldnt-handle-large-requests-fd41b8b5f8e7) explains it in more detail. TL;DR: Upgrade Spring or Tomcat such that you are NOT using v9.0.31.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turned out a weird issue. This is how it's resolved.

- We had checkboxes at the end of the form. The mentioned issue was occurring when we do not select any of the checkboxes. The request was not getting formed correctly and hence server threw error.
- Added a hidden field at the end of the form (make sure this is the last form field) and assigned some value to it.

That' it. Worked like a magic!

More info [here](http://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11).

Comment: I ran into this w/ my grails app accessed from IE10. The hidden field resolved it. FWIW, my form has checkboxes, but they're not the last in the form (2 text fields are).

Comment: After a whole Day of stupid Debugging - thx for this, you are the Best!!!

Answer (score 3):

The issue you have mentioned has troubled me for a long time. I finally have a solution to the issue. IE appends an empty name form data at the end of the formData request object which gets parsed at the server and hence the error occurs.

Below was the form data request object which was sent before the fix:

```
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfToken"

8394D82F5A776708F13CDC6D4B4DE1485C1EC05625E63B2E
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ACTION"

DELETE_LOGO
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ORG_ID"

1879048492
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" 
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c--
```

In order to resolve the issue, added an extra hidden field at the end of the form element.

```
    <csrf:form name="OrgLogoEdit" METHOD="POST" ACTION="/logo" onKeyDown="" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <INPUT TYPE = HIDDEN NAME = "<%= Control._ACTION %>" VALUE = "<%= OrganizationLogo._UPLOAD_LOGO %>">
        <INPUT TYPE = HIDDEN NAME = "<%= Control.ORG_ID %>" VALUE = "<%= organization.getId() %>">

        <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" step="any">
        <input type="hidden" name="dummyIEField"> <!-- this dummy hidden field resolves the stream ended unexpectedly issue -->
    </csrf:form>
```

The request body is now sent as below which is parsed successfully:

```
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfToken"

8394D82F5A776708F13CDC6D4B4DE1485C1EC05625E63B2E
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ACTION"

DELETE_LOGO
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ORG_ID"

1879048492
-----------------------------7e3195134f056c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dummyIEField"


-----------------------------7e3195134f056c--
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I was having only the id attribute and missing the name attribute in the hidden input field which gave me the below error.  Issue resolved after adding the name attribute to the input hidden type field.

id="timestamp" name="timestamp"

Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, the problem was that there was location.reload once document was selected for upload. This stopped the stream to be parsed.