# IE11: Glassfish and Apache Struts - IOFileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: glassfish, internet-explorer-11, struts

Please pardon the long post...

We have a legacy web app that we support that is using Apache Struts 1.2.4 and Glassfish V2.1.1.  I believe the Apache Fileuploads library is 1.0.  The web client allows the user to input several values into different form elements, such as textboxes, selects, checkboxes, etc.  We have many different pages with the number of form elements ranging from 0 to over 100.  Note that some of these elements are hidden from the user.  99+% of the time, it works flawlessly.  However, there are some instances where, during the processing of the HTTP POST request body, we get the exception:

org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:371)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.java:195)

(I'll post the full stack trace upon request.)

The 4 debug statements from the Struts library prior to the exception are:

- Storing ActionForm bean instance in scope 'request' under attribute
  key 'testForm'.
- Populating bean properties from this request.
- File upload temp dir: /data/appsconfig/tmp/.
- Failed to parse multipart request.

Please note that there is no 'file' being uploaded, per se, only the HTTP request body.  I'm assuming that all POSTS with form data are treated as 'files' and saved to a temp folder on the server for processing.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Sometimes, the exact same page with the exact same data will work just fine.  I have been able to capture the request body from both instances of one of the pages.  I have compared the two and save the boundary value differences, the rest of the data is exactly the same.  There are no mal-formed parts of the request nor are there parts that have missing quotes, as have been mentioned in other posts regarding the same topic.

Also, during a previous search, I have seen other posts about adding hidden elements, etc., fixing the data.  That doesn't apply here.  The different pages that have exhibited this problem do not match the criteria for those problems.

The strange parts to this are:
It seems to be kind of size-dependent.  The pages that have failed only fail when they have a large amount of form data to post.  The request body content length is usually over 16k.  What makes it stranger is that sometimes, the same screen will work with slightly different elements and the content length larger than the one that failed.

The other strange part is that it ONLY happens on an IE11 or Edge browser and ONLY while running within the client's own internal network.  When I submit the EXACT SAME page with the EXACT SAME data from my laptop outside of their network it has yet to fail!

Unfortunately, the department that handles the configuration of the web server and apps and firewall and all of that will NOT even help us unless we can give them some concrete evidence that it is worth their time to look into.

I've been banging my head against this for weeks and have gotten some of our top people involved and we really have taken this as far as we can without being able to have their IT department monitor this.  We have monitored it on our side and haven't gotten any better data to work with.

So, I'm asking this brilliant community for help to see if anyone has come across something like this before and for any suggestions you can pass along.

Thank you for your consideration.

Some of the posts I've looked at:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-143

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/332

[IE 11: Error while sending Multipart Form Data request: Stream ended unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903414/ie-11-error-while-sending-multipart-form-data-request-stream-ended-unexpectedl)

Comment: Maybe reference the other [SO] questions on this subject so people know what research has been done.

Comment: Sure.  [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-143)...[link](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/332)...[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903414/ie-11-error-while-sending-multipart-form-data-request-stream-ended-unexpectedl)

Comment: But, you know, not in the _comments_, which can be deleted and are not part of the _question_. This is discussed in [ask]. If you want to attract good (or any) answers, that is.

Comment: "I'm assuming that all POSTS with form data..." No, they're not treated "as files". I'd check any post body size limits set by the app, but if it's only those browsers on that network then you'll probably need to check the request before any processing occurs and check for differences.

Comment: Thanks, jdv.  Added links to question.